# dot NET MAUI Blazor images

Tags: image, blazor, .net-6.0, maui

I'm using dot NET MAUI Blazor to create my new app. I'm struggling to get the images to work. I cant find anything on google. I'm not sure If I should use `<img ImageSource="">` or `<img src="">` nothing works? Is there any type of permission I need to add or what should I use to make an image to display, I tried:

```
ImageSource="Images/snack.png"

ImageSource="snack.png"

src="images/snack.png"

src="snack.png"
```

I do have  included in my .csprog file and also tried  but nothing works

[printscreen of where the image is referenced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxtqI.png)

Comment: You'll probably want to put then in your `wwwroot` folder and see if that works

Answer (score 5):

In my case, somehow this configuration was added in my csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="wwwroot\image\Logo.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This property means to remove specified file.
I deleted this, and then img tag works as I intended.
So, please check your csproj file.

Answer (score 1):

As Gerald suggested, you can create a `images` folder under `wwwroot` like below:

[image]

And then consume it via `src` property like below:

```
<img  src="images/Logo.png"  width="300px" height="300px" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried moving to that folder and tried src="images/Logo.png", src="/images/Logo.png" src="../images/Logo.png" but no luck. I can easily do it on a normal asp.net site and blazor site but the issue is on a blazor maui site

Comment: On my side, the image showed. Would you mind creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via GitHub repo?

Comment: in my case, this works in Windows but not in Pixel 5 Android Emulator...

Answer (score 0):

I have my blazor pages in a separate project from the MAUI project so I have to do

```
<img src="_content/DAB.Pages/images/avatar_upload.png" class="avatar ">
```